# how can i find my public facing ip from python program not proxy

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, centos, ip-address

I want to find my public ip adress from python program.

So far this is the only site

http://www.whatismyip.com/
and
http://whatismyip.org/

which gives ip without proxy rest all give the proxy.

Now .org site is using image and first one writes ip across many span elements so i can't grab with urllib.

Any other idea or site so that i can get my ip

Comment: Did you try http://jsonip.com/. That will save you some html/xml parsing

Comment: What do you mean by "not proxy"? Only some proxies reveal your actual IP address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use http://httpbin.org/:

```
import requests

ip = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').json()['origin']
```

Comment: i got 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @user22: You're using an old version of requests. Upgrade or change `.json()` to `.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

u = urllib.urlopen('http://www.whatismyip.com/')
html = u.read()
u.close()

root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
print ''.join(x.text for x in root.cssselect('#greenip *'))
```